# Unexpected result with left join in MySQL 8

Tags: mysql, left-join, mysql-8.0

I'm using MySQL-8.0.23.

I'm trying to get a list of tables without primary keys in schema 'test'.
I managed to get the expected result using a "not in" statement (cf. code below).
But I' d like to do the same with a left join.

Here are my queries :

```
--------------
-- LIST ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA 'test'
--------------
select
    t.table_name
from
    information_schema.tables t
where
    t.table_schema = 'test'
and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'

+------------------+
| TABLE_NAME       |
+------------------+
| table_with_pk    |
| table_without_pk |
+------------------+



--------------
-- LIST TABLES WITH PRIMARY KEY
--------------
select
    tc.table_name
from
    information_schema.table_constraints tc
where
    tc.table_schema = 'test'
and tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'

+---------------+
| TABLE_NAME    |
+---------------+
| table_with_pk |
+---------------+



--------------
-- LIST TABLES WITHOUT PRIMARY KEY : using "not in" ==> OK
--------------
select
    t.table_name
from
    information_schema.tables t
where
    t.table_schema = 'test'
and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
and t.table_name not in
    (
        select
            tc.table_name
        from
            information_schema.table_constraints tc
        where
            tc.table_schema = 'test'
        and tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
    )

+------------------+
| TABLE_NAME       |
+------------------+
| table_without_pk |
+------------------+


--------------
-- LIST TABLES WITHOUT PRIMARY KEY : using "left join"   ==> NOK
--------------
select
    t.table_name,
    tc.constraint_type
from
    information_schema.tables t
left join information_schema.table_constraints tc
    on t.table_name = tc.table_name
    and tc.table_schema = t.table_schema
    and tc.constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY'
where
    t.table_schema = 'test'
and t.table_type = 'BASE TABLE'

+------------------+-----------------+
| TABLE_NAME       | CONSTRAINT_TYPE |
+------------------+-----------------+
| table_with_pk    | PRIMARY KEY     |
| table_without_pk | PRIMARY KEY     |
+------------------+-----------------+
```

I was expecting the following result with my last request :

```
+------------------+-----------------+
| TABLE_NAME       | CONSTRAINT_TYPE |
+------------------+-----------------+
| table_with_pk    | PRIMARY KEY     |
| table_without_pk | NULL            |
+------------------+-----------------+
```

Can you help me understand what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: Hmm, interesting, in MySQL 5.7 (and 5.5 and 5.5) that behaves as you expect: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=895dc3e3feca15691a2c89a69814a125 But in 8.0 it does not: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=895dc3e3feca15691a2c89a69814a125

Comment: It seems to work on MySQL 5.7 : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=a0253f5c12d13346ac7e7f5788d284ae

Comment: But not on MySQL 8.0 : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a0253f5c12d13346ac7e7f5788d284ae

Comment: Seems like a bug. [MySQL 8.0.12](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jaF8jCqyJVWf8g4sFFFsWb/0) is working as you expect.